# How large must be the sample to determine the probability of a binary outcome?

Tags: probability, random

Suppose a computer program randomly generates a "yes" or "no" answer upon request. You however do not know whether the probability of getting either answer is evenly split or following a different ratio (example: 10% chance "yes" and 90% chance "no").

How many answers should I request from the computer, before having a sample large enough to determine the probability of getting either answer with a margin of error of 1%?

Comment: What exactly is your prior belief? Are you saying that the probability of a Y is $p$ and we believe $p$ is equally likely to take any value in the interval $[0,1]$. So we want to run enough trials to be able to pin it down to $p_0\pm0.01$. Or are you saying that you know there are just two possibilities $p=0.5$ and $p=0.1$ and you want to be $99\%$ certain which it is?

Comment: That's kind of the problem, I don't have any prior belief. the probability of either outcome is completely unknown to me. All I know is that it can be either "yes" or "no".

Comment: Well the standard prior for that is $p$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. So it is now a standard Bayesian calculation. Hmm except that you have no data. So one would have to look at various possible outcomes ...

Comment: Then let's think about an example: I get 10 answers: 7 yes and 3 no. However that I think is not a large enough sample to determine the probability is actually 70% and 30%. My question is how many answers should I get before reaching a moderately certain conclusion

Comment: If no one has answered by then I will look at it first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that our prior information is that the program randomly generates Y with prob $p$ or N with prob $1-p$, where our distribution for $p$ is uniform on the interval $[0,1]$ (meaning we have no idea what the parameter is).

Suppose we then carry out trials and the computer returns Y $m$ times and N $n$ times. The probability of this result with parameter $p$ is simply the binomial ${m+n\choose m}p^m(1-p)^n$, so our posterior distribution for $p$ after the trials is the normalised density $$f(p)=\frac{1}{m+n+1}{m+n\choose m}p^m(1-p)^n$$

Unsurprisingly this gives a distribution with modal value $p=\frac{m}{m+n}$. For example if we got 40 Y in 100 trials, the posterior distribution would be:

[image]

But with only 100 trials our confidence that $p$ is close to 0.4 is fairly low. Integrating, we get that the chance that $p$ lies *outside* the range $0.39<p<0.41$ is 84%.

If we got 400 Y in 1000 trials our posterior distribution would give a 48% chance of $0.39<p<41$:

[image]

If we got 4000Y in 10000 trials we would get a 96% chance of $0.39<p<0.41$:

[image]

So the short answer is that you need of the order of 10,000 trials to get good confidence that you have pinned down $p$ to within 1%.

Of course, you could also use your trials to test whether the Y/N were being randomly generated. Twenty years ago many programmers were hopeless at writing random number generators and they often had obvious regularities. But there have been major improvements since then and the generators built into the major operating systems are now fairly good.